# Passing vector by reference in OpenMP loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp, stdvector

Is it safe to update a vector passed by reference in an OpenMP loop?

In this example, I update the vector `out_vector` from a function inside the parallel loop to which it is passed by reference.

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdlib>

void inner_fun(const std::vector<int>& in_vector, std::vector<int>& out_vector, const std::size_t j, const std::size_t loop_vector_length) {
  
  const std::size_t starting_index = j * loop_vector_length;
  std::srand(starting_index);
  
  for(std::size_t i = starting_index; i < starting_index + loop_vector_length; ++i) {
    out_vector[i] = in_vector[i] + rand() % 10000;
  }
}

std::vector<int> outer_fun(const std::vector<int>& in_vector, const std::size_t loop_vector_length) {
  
  const std::size_t vector_length = in_vector.size();
  std::vector<int> out_vector (vector_length);
  
  #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(5)
  for(std::size_t j = 0; j < vector_length / loop_vector_length; ++j) {
    inner_fun(in_vector, out_vector, j, loop_vector_length);
  }
  
  return out_vector;
}
```

I know that it would be safe to update `out_vector` directly inside the loop. Though, I am not sure whether that also applies to a function inside the loop to which the vector is passed by reference.

I had assumed that this question had been answered on SO, but did not find a respective post. Feel free to mark this question as a duplicate, if you find a post that already answered this question.

Thanks.

Comment: The question should rather be "why this would not be safe?".

Comment: @PierU It would not be safe, if the pointer was somehow affected by the modifications. Because this is already the second of my questions that you comment on within two days, I would like to encourage you to focus on a constructive discussion. Your comments tend to have an aggressive undertone, trying to undermine the post, without advancing the discussion.

Comment: My comment is actually didactic to raise the right question. You have obtained an answer "it is safe", which is correct, but which doesn't say why. The key point is how "pass by reference" works in C++ : the only reason why your code would not be safe is if the "pass by reference" was making (or was allowed to make) a temporary copy of the object (like with the pass by value), and was copying it back to the original object on output of the function.

Comment: @PierU No, the issue would not be with the code making a temporary copy that is then copied back to the original location. The issue is vectors being reallocated. Vectors get reallocated for a number of reasons, e.g. size adjustments. If the inner function's operations would reallocate the vector somewhere else in RAM, the pointer would not refer to the right location anymore.

Comment: Anyway, this discussion is besides the point. It neither clarifies the question, nor does it answer it.

Comment: Which brings back to how “pass by reference” works: afaik it’s just an underlying pointer to the original object, thus it has no reason to induce a reallocation of the vector.

Comment: Yes, I know that this is basically the case. What I was not sure about, was whether OpenMP somehow interferes with that concept. Apparently, it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is safe to do, passing it to a other function by reference doesn't change that.

One remark to the code: With the inner_fun you split the array in chunks and let every chunk be processed by one worker of the parallel region. Such an effect can also be achieved by using a spezific  `schedule` in the omp directive. See the specification for all options https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.1/openmpsu48.html#x73-730002.11.4

Example:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, good point, splitting into chunks is not necessary in this example. I did not take that into account when writing the question.

Comment: @Chr the way you wrote the chunking will correctly work only if `vector_length` is a multiple of `loop_vector_length`

Comment: @PierU I know. That should be obvious from the code.